# ListPicker in WP7 not showing items?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, data-binding, listpicker

XAML:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker  x:Name="payerMenu"  Height="588" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="34,11,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="234" ExpansionMode="ExpansionAllowed"></toolkit:ListPicker>
```

Code behind:

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     payerMenu.ItemsSource = App.Instance.namesList;
}
```

namesList is a `List<string>`. Items are added to that list from another page. When I return to the main page, there are no items shown in the ListPicker. However, I manually print the contents of the ListPicker items in a textblock, all the items are printed

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       foreach(var item in payerMenu.Items)
       {
           textBlock1.Text += item.ToString();
       }
    }
```

This means there items "are" in the ListPicker, for some reason it not showing. I tried hardcoding few items to start with, those items come up in the ListPicker, but not the user added ones.

Answer (score 0):

Check if App.Instance.namesList is a property, not a field.

Comment: it should be correct, because I bound the same list to a listbox on the same page as the listpicker and it works fine. just that the listpicker is not showing the items.

Comment: Can you put more data? How you bound to listbox. How you create source, etc. How you init namesList... and try to bound itemsourece in Xaml.